# PHP disconnected and mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql, connectivity

I have a MySQL query in PHP that deletes multiple row from different tables. I would like to know if when my browser is waiting for the MySQL query to finish if I lost my internet connection will the MySQL query still work on server or will it stop as soon as I lost my connection.

Comment: You running the script at `localhost` or in `live server` ? If you use in live if your internet connection get disconnected then your script will also stop if it has any dependency from your file,

Comment: I'm testing in localhost. In my recent event I run a loop mysql query and I forgot to set a condition. I close my page but it's still inserting untail I close apache or mysql ( i don't remember but I use xampp ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server side will not be affected, if a client loose his connection. 
The request will be excecuted, but the client will not get the result.

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly when a connection to a website that is using PHP is terminated while it is still processing it terminates the script as soon as it is free to do so, so for example while it may break between two `echo` statements it will not break in the middle of a single function such as the MySQL functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you executed something in the server and once the data are sent it will complete the execution and then reload your page and if you loose the connection during sending the data then there is a problem because the data was half sent. the other way is that your data is sent and during the receiving view you lost connection so the data are executed be it mysql or any other database